# #1033 - Incorrect information in file: './database_name/table_name.frm'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

I'm completely lost as to how or why this error is displaying when I go to browse the table data.

The one thing I did notice was that the Storage Engine has been switched to MyISAM with InnoDB saying it has been disabled.

I'm waiting to hear back from the hosting company but is there something I can explore until I hear back from them?

The sql should have been backed up on the server but when I download it, the file is empty.

Any tips on accessing this data is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your host may have disabled InnoDB, which will make any existing InnoDB tables unusable. They may also have accidentally destroyed the InnoDB data file.

Either way, there's nothing you can do yourself to recover it.

Comment: Duskwuff - you were absolutely correct. That's exactly what happened. Thankfully the data wasn't destroyed once they enabled InnoDB.

Comment: Phew! Now it's time to find a web host that won't do horrific things like that. :)

Comment: Mostly this happens when mysqld was killed by the kernel's out of memory killer, and after immediate restart there will be not enough free memory to launch the InnoDB engine. Solution: restart mysqld with enough free memory and run `mysqlcheck -r` on all that tables.

Answer (score 1):

Come to /etc/my.cnf an change config to

```
max_connections = 2500
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 150M
tmp_table_size = 200M
max_heap_table_size = 300M
key_buffer_size = 300M
tmpdir = /dev/shm
```

Run command:
service mysqld restart

check again, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just try to restart mysql. It helped me fix the problem